# make a fragment_layout scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity with navigation drawer. i create a fragment for each items is in my nav drawer. I have a toolbar.xml that included in my content.xml and I want to set my content.xml as default layout for my fragments. but i want to make it scrollable because some of my fragments has many text & images!
I use Scrollview in a Relativelayout in my fragment layout but it doesn't work.

this is my content.xml that I want to set it as my default layout for fragments:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout_for_fragment"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#132740">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my IntroFragment.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context="com.example.arsh.enc.IntroFragment">

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/introfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
        android:text="VERY VERY
VERY VERY

VERY VERY

VERY VERY

VERY VERY LONG TEXT"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

as  I said, i use ScrollView, but there is no result. can anyone tell me where did I go wrong? and what should I do to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take ScrollView's height and width as `match_parent`...

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">



 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -2):

this is my fragment .java class---

```
public class scheduled extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scheduled, container, false);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Started.");
        String []items={"apple","bat","cat","dog","apple","bat","cat","dog","apple","bat","cat","dog"};

        ListView lvdata=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
        lvdata.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

you don't have to add anything extra to make it scrollable. Just add more data
and this is my fragment .xml file---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/listview"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you are right it is already scrollable but there is no need to use ListView